# Show Default values option in store switcher in admin product edit page

Tags: admin, magento-1, magento-enterprise, ee-1.12, store-switcher

I am using **Magento Enterprise Edition** and I am super admin of it.

For some admins, I have allowed only a particular store to be accessed.

For me, the default values option in the store switcher of the product edit page is displayed.

For the admin who has limited access, the default values option is not displayed.
Somebody help me to display the default values option

Comment: which magento version you are using and what permission you have set for the limited access admin user?

Comment: I'm using Magento ver. 1.12.0.2 Enterprise edition. For limited access admin I have given access for single store in admin. Whereas I(super admin) can view all stores @mp196

Answer (score 0):

The default scope is the super admin scope which's scope id is 0(Zero). So it is logically correct, the limited access users should not be able to see/update the super admin scope.

Answer (score 0):

@B G Kavinga is correct.  You are explicitly disallowing access to the default scope for those users.  If they are editing something that can be done at the website or store-level as well as the default and the "Use Default" checkbox is selected, they would see the default value for the next level up.

In the case they have website-level access they would see
[image: Website Level Admin]

In the case they have store-level access, they would see
[image: Store Level Admin]

The store-level would never be able to see the default-scope value, unless it happened to be the same as the website-level.

You may want to consider giving your admins website-level access, which would give them the ability to see the default-scope values, but still be unable to edit it beyond the website-scope.